# Discord list all members python

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I´m trying to make a bot to make a list of members that owns a role I ask (Command: $role Admin Answer: 3 people have role Admin) and when I will ask  (Command: $role list Admin Answer: @Justyn, @JustBoy, @JustBoss).

I tried this code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def members(ctx,*args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    role_name = (' '.join(args))
    role_id = server.roles[0]
    for role in server.roles:
        if role_name == role.name:
            role_id = role
            break
    else:
        await ctx.send("Role doesn't exist")
        return
    for member in server.members:
        if role_id in member.roles:
            await ctx.send(f"{member.display_name} - {member.id}")
```

but when I ask $members Botz, the answer is only "Justyn Bot - 799779320906121236" (On the server I have 8 bots with role Botz but it only lists own bot (itself) ). So I am confused.

If anyone knows how to do it please tell me! Thank you.

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Comment: Probably not? I don´t  even know what is it.

Comment: I see I missed ```@bot.command(pass_context=True)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing members

`Guild.members` requires `intents.members` enabled, to enable them:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(..., intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), ([here's how](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents#privileged-intents))

EDIT

Listing members with a particular role

```py
async def whatever(ctx, role: discord.Role): # The `role` arg will be converted to a `discord.Role` instance
    await ctx.send(f"There's {len(role.members)} users with the role {role.name}")
```

#### Reference:

- [`Guild.get_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_role#discord.Guild.get_role)
- [`Role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_role#discord.Role.members)
- [`Role.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20get_role#discord.Role.name)

Comment: Same as up it´s working, just need to make command that will do "There are X people in role Admin"

Comment: Easiest approach would be getting a `discord.Role` instance and using the `members` attribute, I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: Is there any way to replace ID with name? (so command will be `!role Admin` with answer ` There's X users with the role Admin)

Comment: You can use `RoleConverter`, let me also edit the answer

Comment: Awesome it´s working! Can you edit it so they will understand that first part of answer is for listing users and second part is for writing how many people are in role? I will mark it as answered after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable intents from [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and also you have to define it in your code in order to use some events and methods like `discord.Member.roles`.

In Developer Portal, you have to do:

Select Application -> Bot -> Privileged Gateway Intents -> Enable Presence Intent & Server Members Intent

In your code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<prefix>", intents=intents)
```

For more information, you can check [API References about intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html).

Comment: It´s working! Thank you, and for my second "question" how to make `;role Admin` with answer `There are X people in role Admin` Do you know how to do that? + is there any way to send it as one message (it sends Name - ID, New message Name ID....)

Comment: Like this .js `let roleID = "264410914592129025";
let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members;
console.log(`Got ${membersWithRole.size} members with that role.`);`